# How to get value of searchbox input field on bootstrap-select?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

Here is my html code:

```
 <select id="myselect" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" placeholder="please type" data-live-Search-Placeholder="search">
   <option value="111">AAAAAAAAAAA</option>
   <option value="222">bbbbbbbbbbb</option>
   <option value="333">cccccccccc</option>
</select>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(function(){
   var select1 = $('#myselect').selectpicker();
    //var mysearchkeyword = $('#myselect').selectpicker('search.initiated').val();
    //var mysearchkeyword = $('#myselect').selectpicker('search.input').val();
    var mysearchkeyword = $('#myselect').selectpicker('.bs-searchbox').val();

   select1.on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
    alert(mysearchkeyword);
    
   });
})
```

Here is my fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hgm8t5dx/)

I want to get the data of searchbox input in **bootstrap-select**. For example if I type "a" in searchbox I want it to get the "a" as alert message. I read [this guide](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/1305) and tried a few ways but it didn't work. Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "it didn't work." What happened instead of our expected outcome? I'm not super familiar with `selectpicker()` but it seems to be a way to set the value. what does `select1` contain after you set it?

Comment: @user1599011 It gives me "111" as outcome, the value of AAAAAAAAAAA option. You can test it in my fiddle link.

Comment: What is `.bs-searchbox`? I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that.

Comment: @user1599011 I try to get the input data of the searchbox in bootstrap-select. .bs-searchbox should be the input field of that. As I said before I want to get the data of searchbox input in bootstrap-select. For example if I type "a" in searchbox I want it to get the "a" as alert message.

Comment: Can you tell me what `selectpicker()` does or is meant to be doing here? ".bs-searchbox" doesn't seem to be a valid argument. https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the value will constantly change, I would create the variable as the actual element.

If you look at the DOM structure, you'll see that the `div.bs-searchbox` element is a child of a sibling element to the `$('#myselect')` element.

So, to get the `div.bs-searchbox` element, first get the parent of the `$('#myselect')` element, then use `.find('.bs-searchbox > input')` to search it's dependents, to get the `<input>` child of the `div.bs-searchbox` element (remember that it is the `input` element that has the value of the search, not the `.bs-searchbox` div element).

Then on your event listener, just get the `.val()` of your `searchBoxElement` variable.

See snippet below

```js
$(function() {
  var select1 = $('#myselect').selectpicker();
  //var mysearchkeyword = $('#myselect').selectpicker('search.initiated').val();
  //var mysearchkeyword = $('#myselect').selectpicker('search.input').val();
  //var mysearchkeyword = $('#myselect').selectpicker('.bs-searchbox').val();
  var searchBoxElement = $('#myselect').parent().find('.bs-searchbox > input');

  select1.on('changed.bs.select', function(e) {
    alert(searchBoxElement.val());
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select id="myselect" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" placeholder="please type" data-live-Search-Placeholder="search">
  <option value="111">AAAAAAAAAAA</option>
  <option value="222">bbbbbbbbbbb</option>
  <option value="333">cccccccccc</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This is working just as I want it!!